# Overriding Generated Attachment Post URL

Tags: filters, attachments, uploads

For a plugin I am developing I need image uploads from a Custom Post Type to go to `./wp-content/uploads/clients` instead of `./wp-content/uploads/{YYYY}/{MM}`.

I managed to solve this with the following filter:

```
function client_photo_dir( $param ) {

    if ( isset( $_REQUEST['post_ID'] ) ) {
    $id = $_REQUEST['post_ID'];
    $parent_id = get_post( $id )->post_parent;

    if ( "client" == get_post_type( $id ) || "client" == get_post_type( $parent_id ) ) {
        $args['path'] = CLIENT__UPLOADSDIR;
        $args['url'] = CLIENT__UPLOADSURL;
        $args['basedir'] = CLIENT__UPLOADSDIR;
        $args['baseurl'] = CLIENT__UPLOADSURL;
    }
}

return $args;
}
add_filter( 'upload_dir', 'client_photo_dir' );
```

Files are properly being uploaded to `wp-content/plugins/client-plugin/uploads` as I want them to and they are being added to the Media Library. The problem that has cropped up with this is that the Media Library will show a grey tile instead of a thumbnail of the image and when I click to look at the attachment itself, it shows nothing and the `URL` field is incorrect.

Instead of giving `http://wpdev.localhost/wp-content/plugins/client-plugin/uploads/filename.ext` it is just giving `http://wpdev.localhost/wp-content/uploads/filename.ext` so it can not obviously find it.

The code that handles the upload is:

```
if ( ! empty( $_FILES[$field_name]['name'] ) ) {
    require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php' );
    $override['action'] = 'editpost';

    $file_name = $_FILES[$field_name]['name'];
    $attachment_file = wp_handle_upload( $_FILES[$field_name], $override );
    $post_id = $post->ID;

    $attachment = array(
        'post_title'     => $file_name,
        'post_content'   => '',
        'post_type'      => 'attachment',
        'post_parent'    => $post_id,
        'post_mime_type' => $_FILES[$field_name]['type'],
        'guid'           => $attachment_file['url'],
    );

    // Check if file is a JPEG or PNG and require wp-admin/includes/image.php
    if ( $_FILES[$field_name]['type'] == 'image/jpeg' || $_FILES[$field_name]['type'] == 'image/png' ) {
        require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php' );

        // Temporarily Disable All Defined Image Sizes & Change Upload Directory
        add_filter( 'upload_dir', 'client_photo_dir' );
        add_filter( 'intermediate_image_sizes_advanced', 'remove_image_sizes', 10, 2 );
    }

    $id = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $attachment_file['file'], $post_id );
    wp_update_attachment_metadata( $id, wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $id, $attachment_file['file'] ) );

    // Set metadata value to save to database
    $metadata = $attachment_file['url'];

    if ( $_FILES[$field_name]['type'] == 'image/jpeg' || $_FILES[$field_name]['type'] == 'image/png' ) {
        remove_filter( 'upload_dir', 'client_photo_dir' );
        remove_filter( 'intermediate_image_sizes_advanced', 'remove_image_sizes' );
    }
}
```

I dumped a `print_r()` of both `$attachment_file` and `$attachment` to the `error_log()` and the `['file']/['url'] and`['guid'] values are correctly set respectively.

How do I change that generated URL?

Comment: How are you doing the actual upload? Are these uploads supports to appear in the media library?

Comment: And is this related to your [previous question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/295270/stopping-wordpress-from-auto-generating-image-files-for-sizes)? It really sounds like you're doing the upload the wrong way if you want none of the normal media features.

Comment: @JacobPeattie I updated the question with the part of the `save` method that checks for files and handles uploading them. It doesn't matter if they are added to the media library or not but I do want to keep them in a separate folder. As for the removal of image sizes, I did find the solution to that one with a simple filter that simply returns nothing for the predefined sized.

Comment: You should read this: https://tommcfarlin.com/uploading-files-to-a-custom-directory/

Comment: @JacobPeattie - I actually found a solution that worked using a filter. It's actually very similar to what I originally had but I was able to move it out of the class' `save()` method and add it as a straight up filter for that's always in place based on the post_type. It did introduce a new problem though with the resulting attachment post though.

Comment: You're going to keep running into problems because you're approaching it from the wrong direction. You're using a WordPress function that does one thing then trying to hack it to pieces to do something else. Much simpler approach would be to handle the upload yourself, as described in that article.

Comment: @JacobPeattie - I updated the question. The new issue now is that the `URL` for the resulting attachment post is not being generated correctly. How would I target that? Everything should work once I fix that.